# How to get groups permissions per site collection

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, groups

I need to make a list for all the users and the permissions that they have in the site contents inside a site collection.
 Since all users are getting permissions through SP groups, I need to know the permissions of every SP group.
Practically, I'm trying to get programmatically, the information shown in page:

```
myserver/_layouts/15/viewgrouppermissions.aspx?ID=9999
```

I could scrape out the page but I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found two solutions on this site: [Accessing Group Permissions From PowerShell Using Reflection](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/category/reflection/page/2/)

One solution is with powershell and other one with C#.

Both methods use *reflection so you should not use it in a production system, in other environments use it at your own risk*.

```
# inject fake context 
$site = Get-SPSite("http://intranet.contoso.com") 
$web = $site.OpenWeb() 
$request = New-Object System.Web.HttpRequest("", $web.Url, "") 
$response = New-Object System.Web.HttpResponse(New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter(New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream)) 
$dummyContext = New-Object System.Web.HttpContext($request, $response) 
$dummyContext.Items["HttpHandlerSPWeb"] = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb]$web 
[System.Web.HttpContext]::Current = $dummyContext 
$groupPermissions = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.GroupPermissions 
# set your group here 
$groupId = $web.SiteGroups["Team Site Owners"].ID 
$groupPermissions.GroupId = $groupId 
# set dummy Page 
$groupPermissions.Page = New-Object System.Web.UI.Page 
# invoke private CreateDataTable method 
$groupPermissionsType = $groupPermissions.GetType() 
$bindingFlags = [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic -bor [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::Instance 
$mi_CreateDataTable = $groupPermissionsType.GetMethod("CreateDataTable", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]($bindingFlags)) 
$dataTable = $mi_CreateDataTable.Invoke($groupPermissions, $null) 
#process results 
$regExpPattern = [regex]'<span dir="ltr">(?<scopeUrl>.*?)</span>' 
$dataTable | % { 
  $scopeUrl = $regExpPattern.match($_.ScopeUrl).groups[1].value 
  Write-Host [$scopeUrl] [$_.Role] 
}
```

This is the C# version:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://intranet.contoso.com"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(string.Empty, web.Url, string.Empty);
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse(new System.IO.StreamWriter(new System.IO.MemoryStream()));
        HttpContext dummyContext = new HttpContext(request, response);
        dummyContext.Items["HttpHandlerSPWeb"] = web;
        HttpContext.Current = dummyContext;
        var groupPermissions = new GroupPermissions();
        int groupId = web.SiteGroups["Team Site Owners"].ID;
        groupPermissions.GroupId = groupId;
        groupPermissions.Page = new Page();
        var groupPermissionsType = groupPermissions.GetType();
        var mi_CreateDataTable = groupPermissionsType.GetMethod("CreateDataTable", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        DataTable results = mi_CreateDataTable.Invoke(groupPermissions, null) as DataTable;
        if (results != null)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in results.Rows)
            {
                string rawScopeUrl = row["ScopeUrl"] as string;
                string scopeUrl = rawScopeUrl;
                string regExpPattern = "<span dir=\"ltr\">(?<scopeUrl>.*?)</span>";
                Regex regex = new Regex(regExpPattern);
                Match match = regex.Match(rawScopeUrl);
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    scopeUrl = match.Groups["scopeUrl"].Value;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}] – [{1}]", scopeUrl, row["Role"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code misses ths URL part. It shows the overall permissions of a SP group in a site

Comment: @XristosK answer edited

Comment: That's crazy code man. I've troubles translating to c#

Comment: Welcome to the reflection world lol! btw in the link that I provided to you, there is also the C# version (look the previous post of the blog)